# Any cache profiler for python?

Tags: python, caching, profiler

I'd like to measure the miss rate of cache(L1, L2, or LLC) for a function which is a part of python application. But I am having a problem to find a proper profiler.

I tried "perf" but it seems like it shows the miss rate of the entire application, not a specific function.

Could you guys recommend any profiler for that?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You could, theoretically, run the Python runtime through [valgrind/cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) and at least find where misses occur in the interpreter code which you could somewhat trace back to the actual Python code, but I don't think you'd get very far in optimizing your Python code for its interpreter to reduce cache misses. If you need that level of optimization, Python is probably not the right language to use anyway.